# Manipulate char[] and include result as header file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a question concerning abusing the **C** preprocessor, with this specific example relating to gcc on a Linux system (if that makes a difference).

I want to do something like the following:

```
char filename[] = "hello.txt";
convert_and_include(filename);
```

where convert_and_include changes the last three characters of .txt to be .h and then includes hello.h as a header file.  I know that this likely sounds extremely strange, but I promise you that there is a good reason for wanting to do this.

```
inline void convert_and_include(char filename[]) __attribute__((always_inline))
inline void convert_and_include(char filename[]){
  // Error checking has been removed for clarity.
  filename[6] = 'h';
  filename[7] = '\0';
  filename[8] = '\0';
  #include AS_STRING(filename) // AS_STRING should evaluate to "hello.h"
}
```

Comment: It is not possible.  The preprocessor doesn't understand C.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask about Y, when the real problem is how to do X. So what is your *real* problem.

Comment: I may post a separate question on my real problem.  If so, I'll post the link in the comments section.  I think I'll just write a separate program that does very simple source-to-source compilation.  That should solve my problem.

Comment: @RunFun, you can perhaps play fun games with the `__FILE__` macro and maybe the `#line` preprocessing directive; in principle, these can work in conjunction with the `#include` directive, though I have never seen that actually done.  Before you go off to try that, though, explain your good reason for wanting what you first asked.  We can probably offer a better alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.

The preprocessor runs prior to compilation. All the code and functions are not known to it/understood by it.

The only string manipulations you can do are the ones done by the preprocessor itself (basically string concatenation).